# error for cpp trying to load image but no response

Tags: c++

I am trying to load an image on my window and when I run the code in visual studio code... The window pops up and its just a blank screen... UNTIL I press the exit button on the corner. My image shows up for a second then the window closes.... i you have any idea or comments please let me know thanks! The code can be seen below.

```cpp
<SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

    {
        SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
        SDL_Surface* WindowSurface = nullptr;
        SDL_Surface* image1 = nullptr;
        SDL_Surface* image2 = nullptr;
        SDL_Surface* currentImage = nullptr;
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("sdl Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        WindowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        image1 = SDL_LoadBMP("Red_sheet_full_2.bmp");
        image2 = SDL_LoadBMP("Red_sheet_fullA.bmp");
        currentImage = image1;
        bool isRunning = true;
        SDL_Event ev;
        while (isRunning)
        {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0);
            {
                if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                    isRunning = false;
                else if (ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                {
                    switch (ev.key.keysym.sym)
                    case SDLK_1:
                        currentImage = image1;
                        break;
                    switch (ev.key.keysym.sym)
                    case SDLK_1:
                        currentImage = image1;
                        break;

                }
            }
            
        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(currentImage, NULL, WindowSurface, NULL);

        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_FreeSurface(image1);
        SDL_FreeSurface(image2);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        currentImage = image1 = image2 = nullptr;
        
        
        SDL_Quit();

    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to call something like `SDL_RenderPresent` or `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` to render something to the window?

Comment: You never actually make use of `currentImage` until your event loop ends and you call `SDL_BlitSurface(currentImage, NULL, WindowSurface, NULL)` .